# Using Firebase Database and Firestore both at the same time

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have been reading a bit about Firestore and having a global Firebase Project, I'm of course interested in using Firestore.

Reading this [firebase vs firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#using_cloud_firestore_and_database) page, at the bottom they say we can use both within the same App...

Well, that would be cool but wait...
What about Authentication?
Data Structure being different?
Storage?

With things being different between the two, how is it possible to use both at the same time within the same App?

I can't really picture it.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.
Actually each module have his method :

```
firebase.database() for database
firebase.firestore() for firestore
firebase.auth() for authentication
```

Etc...

And yes, database and firestore have different data structure